# org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

`remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/hibernate-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory. Please see server.log for more details.`

I got error which is above but i have `slf4j-api-1.5.2` and `slf4j12-1.5.2` jars in my project. I searched about this error, everyone said that your project has no `slf4j` jars or you must upgrade your jar files. I ensure have these two stuations. Now i dont know what i have to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide the version of hibernate your are using? If I remember correctly, with version 3.6 or above you should use slf4j 1.6, but I am gonna look this when you provide the hibernate version

Comment: check this out according to your hibernate version: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core

Comment: i have hibernate-3.3.2.GA jar in my project but i also have hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA, hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA, and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final jars. Is there any conflict due to these jars or i must upgrade slf4j version.

Comment: I am not really sure you can use JPA 2 with Hibernate 3.3, try to upgrade to a more recent version of Hibernate (at least 3.5). Also, you can, avoid using Hibernate annotations and stick with standard JPA (therefore you can remove hibernate-annotations and commons-annotations). Are you using Maven?

Comment: No, i am not using maven

Comment: It helps a lot managing dependencies, it will download all the required jar automatically and it will show you the inconsistencies. Have a look!

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#IllegalAccessError - there was a breaking change in slf4j between versions 1.5.5 and 1.5.6. Your version of Hibernate could be calling an older version of slf4j, which would cause this issue. Look at your dependencies and make sure the versions are compatible.